# Recursión infinita en merge sort

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un merge sort con una clase llamada Monitor, utiliza un array de int y tiene los siguientes metodo: size, isEmpty, add, pop, peek.
La cuestión es cuando hago el método merge sort me aparece el error "Stack Overflow Error", merge funciona bien, por lo menos paso el test.

```
public MonitorArray merge(MonitorArray left, MonitorArray right) {
    MonitorArray nuevaLista = new MonitorArray();

    while(!left.isEmpty() && !right.isEmpty()) {
        if(left.peek() <= right.peek())
            nuevaLista.add(left.pop());
        else
            nuevaLista.add(right.pop());
    }

    addAll(nuevaLista, left);
    addAll(nuevaLista, right);

    return nuevaLista;
}


private void addAll(MonitorArray nuevaLista, MonitorArray listaOrdenada) {
    while(!listaOrdenada.isEmpty()) {
        nuevaLista.add(listaOrdenada.pop());
    }
}


public void mergeSort(MonitorArray array) {
    if(array.size() <= 1);
    else {
        MonitorArray left  = firstHalf(array); 
        MonitorArray right = array;

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        array = merge(left, right);
    }
}


private MonitorArray firstHalf(MonitorArray array) {
    MonitorArray half = new MonitorArray();
    int mid = array.size() / 2;
    while(array.size() >= mid) 
        half.add(array.pop());
    return half;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que estás ejecutando tu método `mergeSort` indefinidamente a través de tu variable `right`, ya que el array que le pasas es siempre del mismo tamaño.

```
public void mergeSort(MonitorArray array) {
    if(array.size() <= 1);
    else {
        MonitorArray left  = firstHalf(array); 
        MonitorArray right = array;

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right); // Esta llamada te provoca el overflow
        array = merge(left, right);
    }
}
```